# Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page. Youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, youtube

I would like to play a YouTube video in my iframed page. In index.html I have made a iframe which source is `video.html`. What JavaScript command you can suggest?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="video.html"  id="vidframe" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

video.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Video</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jofNR_WkoCE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by JavaScript commands?

Comment: If i go directly to youtube website and stop video and after that I type this code to browsers url box . It plays a video. javascript:document.getElementById("movie_player").playVideo()

Comment: isn't it better just use `<video>` tag in html5?

Comment: maybe its better, but I want to use javascript command like i posted. I found youtube iframe api website, but i not understantd how to use this in my website. [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: you got src in video html5 tag so you wont have to create each command by yourselfs. However, you can allways search online, I got something that might be usefull for you. http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/dynamically-loading-player-using-javascript

Comment: If I use swf based player I can wrote comands ?

Comment: You can build the controls which allow you to set commands like auto running the video player and stuff like that.